# What's the difference of the subprojects under netty-tcnativa-parent

Tags: java, ssl, netty, tls1.2

After build netty-tcnativa-parent, I fund there generate a jar under each subproject.

```
netty-tcnative-2.0.52.Final.jar
netty-tcnative-classes-2.0.52.Final.jar
netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.52.Final.jar
netty-tcnative-openssl-static-2.0.52.Final.jar
netty-tcnative-libressl-static-2.0.52.Final.jar
```

And most example of netty is using `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.52.Final.jar`. Does the function of these jar are the same but implement differently.

And another question. Am I must install openssl if use `netty-tcnative-openssl-static-2.0.52.Final.jar`.